# How can I position my popup using CSS to a desired location?

Tags: html

`I have designed a project ,where a popup appears upon clicking a button,
but the problem is that the popup doesn't appear in the center.
How can I solve this issue using CSS?

My HTML,CSS and JS code:`

````
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>SabzLearn | Js | 165</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="center">
        <h1>click the button below !</h1>
        <button type="button">Click Here</button>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="modal-parent">
      <div class="modal">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
          dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ulorem lomre t labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <span class="X">&times;</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: you can use fixed or absoulte position css property, the exact problem you are facing is not clear in the question, can you please add some more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it :

```css
.modal{
  background: white;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox:

```
.modal-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); /* Semi-transparent overlay */
}

.modal {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.X {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```